# Is setting variables to null in afterEach preventing memory leaks?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm reading the book [Testing Angular Applications](https://www.manning.com/books/testing-angular-applications), which suggests to reset variables to `null` in the `afterEach` calls. The accompanying text says:

> You can use the teardown part of the test to make sure instances of variables get destroyed, which helps you avoid memory leaks. In this case, you'll use the `afterEach` function to set the `contact` variable to `null`.

Isn't the the used memory freed when the next `beforeEach` sets a new value or at the end of the whole suite when the `describe` call is finished? What's the advantage if any of this explicit teardown?

```
import ContactClass from './contact';

describe('Contact class tests', () => {
  let contact: ContactClass = null;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    contact = new ContactClass();
  });
  
  it('should have a valid constructor', () => {
    expect(contact).not.toBeNull();
  });
  
  afterEach(() => {
    contact = null;
  });
});
```

I don't such a teardown in Angular's testing guide either: https://angular.io/guide/testing-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) issue. It holds an internal reference to everything which is specified outside of the `it()` blocks. In your case this is `contact`. This reference cannot be cleaned up by your browser and therefore not getting garbage collected.

[Here is a blogpost](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/avoid-memory-leaks-angularjs-unit-tests/) dealing with the problem.

*Offtopic: Greetings from a former colleague ;)*

Comment: Seems they've fixed it right around the time the book was published. 
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1154#issuecomment-400135392

It's interesting, I wouldn't have guessed that libraries need to look out for this 

Offtopic: Hehe, very cool to read from you again, what a coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in this case, as you already concluded yourself, because JavaScript uses *garbage collection*.

- For each test case you assign a new value to `contact`. The old value is no longer referenced and can be garbage collected.
- At the end of the test suite the `contact` variable goes out of scope and its value can be garbage collected.